# Why can't i load an image to my React App?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-router, react-bootstrap

I can't load an image to my React App by some components

[Here is Herosection.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0jal.png)

[Herosection.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgGVf.png)

[Home.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXs46.png)

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9CdR.png)

Comment: Please fix your question since, as it is now, it is unreadable.

Comment: @Dang Welcome to the SO, but you have to add your code as code snippets so, we can copy and edit that code to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

The path to the image is not correct. By default, you should include all the images related to the project **inside** the project, not outside of it.